# How to sign every ocx, dll and exe file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, codesign

I am using signtool to sign my files.

How to recursively search all the ocx, dll and exes  in a folder and subfolder then sign them all using Command Prompt ? I want to sign only the ones developed by me and not the third party ones.

Comment: Normally with installers you don't sign every file in the package but include [a catalog file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that has a hash of all the files and just sign the catalog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
@echo off FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /s *.dll *.ocx *.exe') DO ( echo %%G set A= "%%G" signtool sign /f "C:\Certificates\FakeCertificate.pfx" %A%
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

The rub here is how to distinguish your binaries from third party binaries. You could create a whitelist or if you have consistently marked your binary fileversioninfo with your company name, you can take this approach:

```
Get-ChildItem *.* -r -inc *.dll,*.ocx,*.exe | 
    Where {($_ | Get-FileVersionInfo).CompanyName -match 'your-company-name'} | 
    Foreach {signtool sign <options> $_.Fullname}
```

Note: this approach uses a command (Get-FileVersionInfo) from the PowerShell Community Extensions which can be downloaded [here](http://pscx.codeplex.com).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, I will prefer a command which doesn't require powershell?

Comment: Then why did you tag your question with PowerShell and PowerShell-v2.0?

Comment: I will prefer a command which doesn't require powershell but I will use powershell command and mark your above answer as answer if it works and I don't get one without using powershell. Prefer to add another answer as I am upvoting this anyway and even the powershell command will help.

Comment: This is slow, is there a way to do it in parallel?